# How to url clean

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know how to proceed.I want clean URL with hypen on each space and special chars too to be replaced or removed but when this needs to be happen before going to database?

So, if saved to dabased with new url with spaces how to revert back to original url for titles, therefore it will be appear with spaces.
Do I need to create 2 columns - one for title which will visualised for user and other column for URL.

I'm tried with this function which works perfect:

```
function clean_url($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}
```

Comment: yes you have to use another column for the  URL, usually called "slug"

Comment: yes,
http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator

Comment: But some people used only one column for title therefore title is URL.In database it not be cleaned it contains special chars etc. but URLs is clean from spaces with hypen.How they clean URLs without inserted into database ?

Comment: Then 1) Store only the title. 2) Apply the title-to-url conversion function each and every time when outputting a link. 3) Wonder how your code got so obtuse and slow.

Comment: But if convert with function I think it will search for title from database and not be found.For example if saved to database: mylink 123 # and converted will mylink-123--- in database only have  mylink 123 # and.